# C# setter changes value to 0

Tags: c#

I have encountered a problem with a setter while programming a board game in C#.

Here I have a if statement where I get a new random number and try to update the position of my player p.

```
if(Console.ReadLine().Equals("Y"))
{
  int roll = dice.roll();
  Console.WriteLine(p.playerName + " rolled: " + roll);
  int newPosition = p.position + roll;
  p.position = newPosition;

  Console.WriteLine("The players position is: " + p.position);
}
```

Here is the setter for the position in the Player class.

```
public int position
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Position is: " + position);
            _position = position;
        }
    }
    private int _position;
```

My problem is that the value seems to change to zero in the setter.

OUTPUT:

Roll? (Y/N)Y

Player 1 rolled: 4

Position is: 0 // Printed in the Player position setter

The players position is: 0 //This is printed when getting the value from the player object

Why is the value of position 0 in the setter when I am sending it a value, like 4?

Comment: Try `_position = value;` instead of `_position = position;` in the setter.

Comment: This solved it! Thank you Oliver.

Comment: Assuming this is modern C#, you can just write `public int Position { get; set; }`. If you are using Unity, I *think* this is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setter calls the `get` of the property, which returns the actual value at that moment, probably `0`. You need to use `value` which is the incoming value:

```
set
{
    Console.WriteLine("Position is: " + value);
    _position = value;
}
```

Read more about the `value` keyword on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your setter never *sets* a value, it simply uses the existing property value. Since that value was never set, it's the default integer value of 0.

Instead of

```
 _position = position;
```

you should use

```
_position = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use `position` which is the property instead of `value` which is the property argument. That's why you assign `0`, it is the initial value returned from the getter:

```
public int position
{
    get
    {
        return _position;
    }
    set
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Position is: " + position);
        // _position = position; // <-- NO, that's using the getter so _position
        _position = value;       // <-- Yes, this is the argument
    }
}
private int _position;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your code there. Inside the set you are accessing position. But position is what the setter is for. In essence you are getting the current position and set it as the new value. And the current position I take is 0 as you get 0 (as its an int it is also possible that 0 is the default value instead of null as for string).

Setters have the new value in the variable "value" as that is where it is defaultwise stored. So with that in mind your code should be:

```
    public int position
    {
        get
        {
            return _position;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Position is: " + value);
            _position = value;
        }
    }
    private int _position;
```